# Conditional Access Policy - Block Exchange Active Sync

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

We moved most in our company to outlook for mobile app on there phones, however some have not yet moved. We want to block exchange active sync via CA policies. I'm most positive I set it up correctly however a few users that I placed in the include policy are still able to use it. Please see policy below and if anyone has any ideas that would be great thanks.

Note : We do not have Intune and have no plans on purchasing. Also we have all users under an azure p1 plan.

```
Policy

    Users and Workloads
-Include
--Users in question

Cloud Apps or actions
-All Cloud Apps (include)

Conditions
-Client Apps
--Exchange Active Sync

Access Controls
-Grant
--Block Access
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To block exchange active sync via CA policies please check this [official document](https://www.adamfowlerit.com/tag/conditional-access/) make sure before using conditional policy try to ***Enable security defaults as yes***

[image]

In Conditional Access Policy follow the below steps;

- In ***Users and groups*** select ***all users***
- ***Cloud apps or actions*** click Select Apps and import ***Office 365 Exchange Online***
- In ***condition*** at device platform select any device and in client apps select ***Mobile apps and desktop clients*** and ***Exchange***
- ***Grant block access*** and enable policy

For more information in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Blocking ActiveSync with Conditional Access](https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2019/09/blocking-activesync-with-conditional-access/#:%7E:text=Via%20the%20Azure%20Portal,%20go,options%20and%20press%20%27Apply%27.) credits by ***Adam Fowler***

Comment: This article does not look the same as mine, Mobile Apps and Desktop Clients are not in preview. Also If i block "mobile apps and desktop clients wont it block Outlook?

Comment: Please check this [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/exchange-activesync/activesync-mailbox-access?view=exchserver-2019) & [Clients and mobile Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online)